# emgu two hands detection

Tags: c#, emgucv, image-segmentation, haar-wavelet

I want to detect two hands (using HSV filtered image).

the problem is that when i get the two hands together the head gets in between and then the hands cannot be recognized.

im using Haar to detect the 2 hands when the application starts and then i turn the image into HSV (black and white). then im using segmentation to detect the objects central mass so i can follow them. i dismiss the objects which their area is small enough.

any ideas how can i solve this problem ?